# Python - download a file from a ftp server to a different local name

Tags: python, ftp, download

I have the following code:

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP(ftp_srv)
ftp.login(ftp_usr, ftp_pass)

for item in list:
    f = open(item.localName,"wb")
    ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + item.remoteName, f.write)
ftp.quit()
```

- "localName" is the name of the file on the local machine, for example: one.txt
- "remoteName" is the name of the file on the FTP server with full path, something like "/share/path/to/file.txt"

In perl this was very easy:

```
 $ftp->get($ftp_file, $local_file)
```

EDIT:
The code above does not work. I would like to download the remoteName file to the local machine and on the local machine that file to be named localName. How do I do that? :D 
EDIT2: made it a list

Thank you

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: The code above does not work. I would like to download the remoteName file to the local machine and on the local machine that file to be named localName. How do I do that? :D  Thank you

Comment: This script can't work (there are no list, localName or remoteName variables) - is this supposed to be pseudo code or the real failing script?

Comment: ... and by "does not work" how doesn't it work? Show us the error.

Comment: This is not pseudo code, this is the actual code, I just removed some part because it was not relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problems with your code are that:

- `item` is never actually used in the `for` loop
- `localName` or `remoteName` are not specified anywhere

This code works on my machine:

```
import ftplib

ftp_srv = 'ftp.example.com'
ftp_usr = 'user'
ftp_pass = 'password'

ftp = ftplib.FTP(ftp_srv)
ftp.login(ftp_usr, ftp_pass)

files = [('remote_file1', 'local_file1'), ('remote_file2', 'local_file2')]

for file_ in files:
    with open(file_[1], "wb") as f:
        ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + file_[0], f.write)
ftp.quit()
```

Each `file_` is a [tuple](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Tuples) which contains the name of the file on the server, and the name you want it to have on your local machine, which are referred to using the square bracket notation.

Comment: good example except that the final output file remains open after for loop completes, how about using `with open(file_[1], "wb") as f:` instead?

Comment: Do I need to change the working directory or I can download the file using full path? I tried using full path but I get an error and I don't know if it's something that I'm doing wrong or if it's something that should now work.

Comment: You can use the full path, but you have to make sure that all directories along the path exist. For example, if you're writing to `/tmp/mydir1/local_file`, you have to create `mydir1` before running the script, or add code to create the directory before writing to it.

Comment: This works, I did something wrong...n00b mistake (n00b that I am) - I added something to the path that was not there. Thank you all for your help!